# how to remove certain words from a line of text in c

Tags: c

I got my code working to an extent, but I need some more help. If I needed to remove the word "an", from sentence: "I ate an apple whilst looking at an ape.", it only removes the first "an" and not the second, how do I repeat the loop so it deletes all "an"s? I need the final sentence, after the code has been ran, to be: "I ate apple whilst looking at ape.". That is the goal im trying to achieve

Sorry for not including the code.
Here it is:

```
#include "RemoveFromText.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int findFirstSubstring(char textToChange[], char removeThis[])
{
    int size = strlen(textToChange);
    int subStringLength = strlen(removeThis);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(textToChange[i] == removeThis[0])
        {
            int j = 0;
            while(textToChange[i+j] == removeThis[j])
            {
                j++;
                if(j==subStringLength)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void removeFromText( char textToChange[], char removeThis[])
{

    int textLength = strlen(textToChange);
    if(findFirstSubstring(textToChange, removeThis) >= 0)
    {
        int subStringIdx = findFirstSubstring(textToChange, removeThis);
        int loopVariabele = 0;

        for(loopVariabele = subStringIdx; loopVariabele<textLength; loopVariabele++)
        {
            textToChange[loopVariabele] = textToChange[loopVariabele + strlen(removeThis)];

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Usually removing a word involves also to remove the space char after the word itself.

Comment: The 'removeFromText' does not loop over multiple occurrences. Also the function 'findFirstSubstring' is available in the standard library as 'strstr'

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging 'strstr', and 'memmove' standard "C" library functions

```
// Remove all occurences of 'source' from 'message'.
void removeAll(char *message, char *source)
{
    int len = strlen(source) ;
    for (char *x = message ; x=strstr(x, source) ; ) {
        // Copy everything after 'source', including terminating nul.
        memmove(x, x+len, strlen(x+len)+1) ;
    } ;
}
```

Notes:

1. that solution that not properly address the trailing space(s) after a word. This can be addressed by chaning the 'memmove'.
2. Probably make sense to make the function return the number of substitutions, or some other meaningful result